# Matrix transformations in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, coordinate-transformation

I'm building a 2D physics engine in Java using OpenGL (from [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/)) to display the objects. The problem I am having is that the transformation matrices I apply to the frame seem to be getting applied in a different order to what it says that are.

```
/**
 * Render the current frame
 */
private void render() {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), 0, Display
            .getDisplayMode().getHeight(), -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth() / 2, Display
            .getDisplayMode().getHeight() / 2, 0.0f);

    renderFrameObjects();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

public void renderFrameObjects() {
    Vector<ReactiveObject> objects = frame.getObjects();
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        ReactiveObject currentObject = objects.get(i);
        Mesh2D mesh = currentObject.getMesh();

        GL11.glRotatef((float)(currentObject.getR() / Math.PI * 180), 0, 0, 1.0f);
        GL11.glTranslated(currentObject.getX(), currentObject.getY(), 0);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_POLYGON);
        for (int j = 0; j < mesh.size(); j++) {
            GL11.glVertex2d(mesh.get(j).x, mesh.get(j).y);
        }
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glTranslated(-currentObject.getX(), -currentObject.getY(), 0);
        GL11.glRotatef((float)(-currentObject.getR() / Math.PI * 180), 0, 0, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

In renderFrameObjects() I apply a rotation, a translation, draw the object (mesh coordinates are relative to the object's x, y), reverse the translation, and reverse the rotation. Yet the effect it gives when an object rotates (on collision) is similar to when one would apply a translation then a rotation (ie. rotates around a point at a radius). I can't seem to be able to figure this one out having tried various combinations of transformations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is beacause they are applied to the local coordinate system of the object, not the object itself.

So the rotate rotates the coordinate system and the translation is applied within that rotated coordinate system.

BTW: Don't undo your matrix changes by applying negative transformations. Roundoff error's will accumulate and it probably is also less efficient then using glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm not sure how I would implement it. What I've done previously is rotate then translate and it's worked fine. Regardless, thanks for the popping tip, it does that now. Also, it turns out I need to rotate the mesh itself for collision detection so I don't need to rotate at rendering time.

Comment: Apply translation first, then rotation.